# Erro ao Inserir: Incorrect integer value 'EXAMPLE' for column 'id_example' at row 1

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-insert, visual-studio-2017

Eu estou a tentar inserir na minha base de dados mySQL através do Visual Studio 2017 - C# (localhost-wamppserver) mas está a dar erro.

A primeira coluna da tabela registos é a id_registo que é a chave primaria da tabela registos e é auto_increment e sendo assim não a especifiquei no Insert Into.

Mas por alguma razão o erro está a dar ao inserir no id_tipos que é a chave estrangeira da tabela tipos, penso que será por estar a usar uma `combobox` com os valores da coluna nome_tipo da tabela tipos e a inserir os registos na tabela registos porque os campos com `textbox` estão perfeitos, o erro está descrito abaixo e no titulo da pergunta.

Será por os valores da combobox serem texto e a coluna em que estou a inserir ser uma chave estrangeira INT?

Eu estou a ter o erro seguinte ao inserir:

```
Incorrect integer value: 'TEXT' for column 'id_tipos' at row 1
```

A minha query:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO `registos`(`data`, `id_tipos`, `id_tec`,`id_processo`, `id_tarefa`, `horas`, `com`) VALUES ('" + datatp_1.Text + "','" + comboBox_tipo1.Text + "','" + comboBox_tec1.Text + "','" + comboBox_pro1.Text + "','" + comboBox_passos1.Text + "','" + txt_horas1.Text + "','" + txt_com1.Text + "')";
```

A minha consulta select * from registos:
[image: BD]

A minha consulta select * from registos + INNER JOIN:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você colocou o segundo valor entre parênteses sendo que ele é um `int`. Qual é o valor que você está passando? Mostre-nos a `query` formada

Comment: Essa parte `'" + comboBox_tipo1.Text + "'`, você está tentando adicionar um texto onde deveria ser um inteiro. Remova os `'` antes e depois!

Comment: Como assim query formada? query no workbench?
Não sei se te referes a isso mas, meti o print na pergunta em cima

Comment: Marconi removi os ' ' e continuou a dar o mesmo erro amigo

Comment: O que eu te indicaria é debugar seu código e pegar o valor assim que passar por essa linha, depois jogar a query no banco e verificar o que há de errado.

Comment: Marconi tem discord para uma ajuda mais personalizada? estou a estagiar e sou "novo" em programação, sera que me podias ajudar mais detalhadamente

Comment: @gmbc sim, faz o que te falei acima. Verifica como está esta variável `query` através do debug.

Comment: @Marconi vou tentar agora, 2minutos, se poder adicionar no discord é melhor: Jøycelyn#3447

Comment: @Marconi fiz o debug, selecionou a query e agora?

Comment: Comenta aqui pra mim ver o resultado

Comment: Links do imgur : https://imgur.com/a/PznHHWa
A query não da erro, só aparece aquela messagebox no momento do inserir

Comment: Tinha que ser depois da variavel pra ver o resultado dela.

Comment: Por isso que perguntei se tinha discord secalhar era mais facil se eu partilhasse o ecrã, o erro (messagebox)  so da quando chega no catch